# SQL formatting/escaping injection with raw(...)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I am using a query in django. While I normally do this directly in the sql connector, sometimes I use the `raw(...)` method, for example as follows:

```
items_from_master = list(ItemMaster.objects.raw(
    """SELECT * FROM main_itemmaster WHERE 
       (content_type_id != 'TV Season') AND (MATCH(name) against('%s')) LIMIT 20
       UNION 
       SELECT * FROM main_itemmaster WHERE name='%s'
       ORDER BY imdb_votes DESC LIMIT 30""" % (q,q)))
```

Is there a way to escape the string here? For example, something like `cursor.execute(sql, params)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw(...)` [supports a `params` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) for exactly this case.

Note the removal of the quotes from your original query:

```
items_from_master = list(
    ItemMaster.objects.raw(
        """
        SELECT * FROM main_itemmaster WHERE 
        (content_type_id != 'TV Season') AND (MATCH(name) against(%s)) LIMIT 20
        UNION 
        SELECT * FROM main_itemmaster WHERE name=%s
        ORDER BY imdb_votes DESC LIMIT 30
        """,
        [q, q],
    ),
)
```

This can also take a dictionary, which is a bit cleaner in cases like yours where one value is used multiple times:

```
items_from_master = list(
    ItemMaster.objects.raw(
        """
        SELECT * FROM main_itemmaster WHERE 
        (content_type_id != 'TV Season') AND (MATCH(name) against(%(q)s)) LIMIT 20
        UNION 
        SELECT * FROM main_itemmaster WHERE name=%(q)s
        ORDER BY imdb_votes DESC LIMIT 30
        """,
        {"q": q},
    ),
)
```